# How to use a variable located in a 2D array in another method?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, 2d, element

I'm having trouble using a couple of variables (the row and column number) I'm getting in other methods. Here is the code:

```
public class playerPos {

private int rowT;
private int colT;

    public void setPos(String field[][]){

        for(int i = 0; i<field.length;i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<field[i].length; j++){
            if(field[i][j] == "6"){
                rowT = i;
                colT = j;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

now when I print *inside* the loop, or anywhere inside this method really, rowT and colT have the correct values. However, when I try to use rowT and colT in other methods (in the same class), they always return 0. Why is this?
continuation of code above:

```
    public Integer getRowT(){
    System.out.println("rowT from get : " + rowT);
    return rowT;
}

public Integer getColT(){
    System.out.println("colT from get : " + colT);
    return colT;
}
```

}

thanks for any help!

More code:

```
public class Home {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Field start = new Field();
    Print first = new Print();

    first.popField(start.newField());


    logInput input = new logInput();

    **playerPos position = new playerPos();
    position.setPos(start.newField()**);                                    

            **Move way = new Move();**
    first.popField(way.MoveP2(start.newField(), input.trekker, input.direction));

}
```

}

```
public class Move {

public String[][] MoveP2(String field[][], String trekker, int direction){

    playerPos pos = new playerPos();            
    Field type = new Field();               

    int rowT = pos.getRowT();               
    int colT = pos.getColT();
```

...
}

Comment: int fields are automatically initialized to 0.

Comment: yes, I know, but the variables are meant to take a different value in the loop, and they *do*, but that doesn't follow through - why?

Comment: @Jona, I hope you call, setPos() method before calling getRowT() or getColT()

Comment: @sasankad I wish it were so simple - they're both in the same class, and I call them in separate methods, but setPos() certainly gets called before getRowT and getColT

Comment: Show us exactly when you are calling those methods. The codes that you have posted now, doesn't help at all.

Comment: @Jona, Then it should work as long as same object instance used to call in those two separate places

Comment: hopefully that helps to understand the code. thanks for the tip sasankad

Comment: Please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the issue you are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your `MoveP2` method to parse the `PlayerPos` object as an argument

```
public String[][] MoveP2(playerPos pos, String field[][], String trekker, int direction){

    Field type = new Field();               

    int rowT = pos.getRowT();               
    int colT = pos.getColT();
... }
```

and in you `Home` class `main` method modify the `MoveP2` to parse the `PlayerPos` object you already created as follows

```
first.popField(way.MoveP2(position, start.newField(), input.trekker, input.direction));
```

then it should work. And please follow java coding standards like methods name should start with a lower case letter

Comment: you blessed creature of the internet, thank you! you've taught me 3 new things. I'm very grateful. (didn't know about the method caps convention!)

Answer (score 0):

in your `MoveP2` method you're instantiating a new `playerPos` instance which will have separate `rowT` and `colT` from the `playerPos` object in your main method.  Try passing the the `playerPos` instance `position` from your main method as a method parameter to your `MoveP2` method and use that in the method.

Comment: sounds like that would work, but I don't know how to pass a method as a parameter. I'm searching stackOverflow and I keep seeing reference to a "callable interface" like this:

Comment: public T myMethod(Callable<T> func) {
    return func.call();
},

but where do i do this - in the main?

Comment: your position variable is a variable, not a method, pass it as a parameter to the MoveP2 method.